# Raising SIGINT, but getting stuck in thread in c

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

I'm doing a program that utilizes threads. I also have a `SIGINT` handler that closes everything correctly, for an orderly shutdown. However, since my threads are in a `while(1)` loop the `pthread_join` function in my handler gets stuck and i have to press `ctrl+c` a bunch of times, to close each thread singularly. How can i do this with just 1 click?
Here's my thread worker function:

```
void *worker(){
    struct message msg;
    while(1){
      if(wr.fnode != NULL){
        sem_wait(&tsem);
        stats->nptri++;
        msg.patient = *(wr.fnode);
        wr_deletefnode();
        sem_post(&tsem);
        sleep((float)(msg.patient.ttime/1000));
        msgsnd(mqid,&msg,sizeof(msg)-sizeof(long),0);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call pthread_join?

Comment: Post your signal handler.  "I also have a SIGINT handler that closes everything correctly, for an orderly shutdown." sounds like you may be calling non-async-signal-safe functions from within the signal handler, which is one very good way to deadlock a process.

Answer (score 1):

It's depend how you are sending `signal` (SIGINT or any) to a `thread`. for sending a signal to thread you should use `pthread_kill()` instead of `kill()` or `raise()` because signal handler(`signal or sigaction`) handles only `processes` ,not `threads`.

```
 int pthread_kill(pthread_t thread, int sig);
```

If you ever try to kill running thread using kill command/function OS will throw warning like `Warning: Program '/bin/bash' crashed.`

observe running thread using `ps -eL | grep pts/0` before and after sending signal.

I hope you got something.

Comment: What if the thread is in the middle of it's work and i want/need it done before the `pthread_kill` can send any signal to it. Is there a way of blocking and unblocking a thread from receiving a certain signal? Thank you for your response.

Comment: I didn't tried befoe but you can use `pthread_cond_signal()`   it will unblock threads which is blocked on conditional variable. check man page there are so many, you will get.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to solve:

1. How to break the endless while loop
2. How to return from blocking system call (like for example `sem_wait()`)

---

Referring 1.:

Change

```
while (1)
```

to be

```
while (!exit_flag)
```

Define `exit_flag` globally

```
volatile sig_atomic_t exit_flag = 0;
```

and set it to `1` on reception of the `SIGINT` signal.

To catch a signal do not setup a signal handler, but create a separate thread using `sigwait()` to wait for and receive a `SIGINT`.

Make sure all other threads are created blocking `SIGINT`.

---

Referring 2.:

Keep track of  all thread running by memorising their thread-ids.

After the signal-listener thread mentioned under 1. set the `exit_flag`, then loop over the list of running threads and one by one

- enable them to receive `SIGINT`
- signal them using `pthread_kill()`, in case they were stuck inside a system call, the call would return setting `errno` to `EINTR`.
- join the thread calling `pthread_join()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunatly i am required to use a handler to catch my signals otherwise yours would be a more elegant solujtion. About the , `exit_flag` part. Isn't that doing an active wait? Don't know if the term is correct (i'm translating it from my own language).

Comment: @jonelearn: "*Isn't that doing an active wait?*" I do not understand this question? If you need to use a signal handler, inside it set the `exit_flag` and inside the dedicated termination thread as mentioned under 1. replace the call to `sigwait()` by `while (!exit_flag) { sleep (1); }`.

Comment: You've a typo. Should be "Make sure all other threads are created **blocking** `SIGINT`".

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Hu! Thanks. Fixed.